# NHibernate Oracle Single incorrect Precision

Tags: oracle, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Oracle9i and NHibernate 3.1.0.4 and FluentNhibernate 1.2.0.712

NHibernate is configured as follows...

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=ORA9TEST;User ID=NOPE;Password=NOPE;</property>
      <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

It generates this insert statemanet

```
2012-08-10 16:33:36,380 [DEBUG] 15  NHibernate.SQL                      - 

INSERT INTO FACT_Data (STime, subg_number, subg_index, measurement, Rj, InvalidSpec, data_uid, WrittenState, dept_id, specs_id, data_id) VALUES (:p0, :p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5, :p6, :p7, :p8, :p9, :p10);:p0 = 2/7/2012 12:49:57 AM [Type: DateTime (0)], :p1 = 103 [Type: Int32 (0)], :p2 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)], :p3 = 30.346 [Type: Single (0)], :p4 = 0 [Type: Single (0)], :p5 = False [Type: Boolean (0)], :p6 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)], :p7 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)], :p8 = 2 [Type: Int32 (0)], :p9 = 45423 [Type: Int32 (0)], :p10 = 1178436 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

The Column FACT_Data.Measurement is type NUMBER(*,6)

When I read that row back out, instead of the Measurement value being 30.346 it is 30.346001.  What can I do to make it store my Single value correctly without the extra 0.000001?

Please and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Decimal instead of Single if you need this kind of precision.

You can find more information about floating point types here: [decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

Comment: In the Oracle I have, 9i, DECIMAL(*,6) is the same as NUMBER(*,6).  Using that, I get the same results "30.346001"...

Comment: I meant in your .net application. You should use the Decimal type there. In Oracle it makes no difference.

Comment: That looks like it did it, but what is the (best) matching datatype in Oracle for Decimal, FLOAT or NUMBER?

Comment: Data types in oracle: http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html. FLOAT is just a synonym for the NUMBER type. So it is the same. Decimal Type in .net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.80).aspx ... that means it would not make sense to create numbers in oracle with a higher precision than the one of a Decimal (if you use a Decimal).